# Will Ubuntu work with my computer?

Tags: system-installation

I am currently using Windows XP Professional, Version 5.1.2600 Service pack 3 build 2600. It is a Dell Dimension 9200. It has an Intel Core 2 CPU 6300 @ 1.86GHz with 2GB of RAM. I have slightly over 95GB space on the hard drive. Will Ubuntu work or would I have better luck using lubuntu?

Edit: Specifically, I am wondering if the Intel Core 2 CPU is going to work because the recommended requirements say a dual core processor. Is this a dual core? Do I just need to reach the minimum requirements for Ubuntu to work properly?

Answer (score 1):

You can try Ubuntu (or Lubuntu, or any flavour) without need to install it, by using a LiveCD. There, you can see how Ubuntu would work in your PC.

The steps are very simple:

- [Download](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) the flavor of Ubuntu you want to test
- Burn the ISO into a USB/CD/DVD. A simple guide [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BurningIsoHowto)
- Boot the USB/CD/DVD as if you were to install it.
- Select "Try Ubuntu without any change to your computer" from the menu.

There you have, Ubuntu in your PC! Now try it, play with it, and see how it performs in your PC. You can do this for several flavors and see which fits your needs better.

There are plenty of guides online for LiveCD. For example, [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCD).